# Recuperar pregunta

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

[Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40726/como-generar-un-v%C3%ADdeo-desde-un-audio-e-im%C3%A1genes-con-php) fue eliminada por el OP, no se los motivos por los que lo hizo, pero creo que es una buena pregunta, ademas @rnd la respondió muy bien, 
estaba esperando si alguien más votaba por recuperarla pero veo que no es así, se podría hacer algo para recuperarla y reabrirla??

Comment: ya se recuperó. Y con el voto que le di a la respuesta de @rnd, no creo que OP pueda removerla ya. Disculpa mi indiscreción, pero si te pareció buena su respuesta, ¿porqué no le votastes a favor? Hubiera evitado que sea eliminada.

Comment: @sstan El momento que revise la respuesta de rnd ya estaba marcada como demasiado amplia, también estaba desde un teléfono celular por lo que no puse atención en la votación positiva, cuando la revise en la pc ya estaba eliminada. Gracias por el voto de reapertura, es buena pregunta y tiene una buena respuesta :-)

Comment: Gracias gente, no se como fue que la borre. un error totalmente involuntario XD.

Comment: En ocasiones los OP borran sus preguntas pero no especifican el motivo, me parece lo pueden realizar si no se realiza un voto en la pregunta o respuesta, por ejemplo:  http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42569/problema-con-asynctask/42581

Comment: @Elenasys No puedes eliminar *tu propia pregunta* si: **(1)** tiene una respuesta con un voto a favor, **(2)** tiene una respuesta aceptada, o **(3)** tiene múltiples respuestas (por más que no tengan votos a favor). Además, **(4)** no puedes eliminar *ninguna* de tus preguntas o respuestas si no has registrado tu cuenta (asociándola con un OpenID). Fuente: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/127

Comment: Oh gracias por la información Mariano.