# Me gustaría recuperar una pregunta eliminada por el OP

Tags: soporte, cierre-de-preguntas

Al igual que ha pasado con [Recuperar pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1255/recuperar-pregunta), me gustaría recuperar la pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/362799 eliminada por el OP. Creo que ilustra un error muy común.

Comment: Esa pregunta se podría considerar un [duplicado de esta otra pregunta del mismo usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/362436/250). No sé si merece la pena recuperarse teniendo eso en cuenta.

Comment: Pues sí, hasta con los mismos datos... :(

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque la pregunta a la que se referencia se había publicado dos veces y esta fue la que borró